# Is it undefined behavior to redeclare a variable within enclosed scope?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    if(true) {
        int i = 5;
        cout << i << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Tried running the above code on Ideone to see if its legal. The results perplex me:

- We have a compilation error [(1)](https://ideone.com/HPjUSM), [(2)](https://ideone.com/Qg4FIp)
- Or this code prints `5` as expected [(1)](https://ideone.com/6xiUXR)
- Or it prints nothing [(1)](https://ideone.com/dc2IN2), [(2)](https://ideone.com/DVQiu3)

As you can see from my links this same code behaves radically differently each time it is compiled on Ideone! This smells like undefined behavior (UB).

OK C++ is known for its unintuitive behaviors BUT! - I admit its just my intuition but I wouldn't expect even C++ to make redeclaring a variable in an inner scope UB! Id expect either shadowing or mandatory compilation error.

Is my code really UB according to the C++ standard, or is it just a peculiarity of Ideone and/or gcc? If its UB, is it UB because I redeclared `i` or for some other reason I'm failing to notice now?

Comment: There is no UB in your code.  This just makes me want to avoid IDEOne even more.  Too bad it doesn't say what the compiler error is.

Comment: This is perfectly valid. The two `i`s are completely separate variables. I forked your `(1)` code and it ran unchanged with no error.

Comment: Not specific to the question, but run away from online compilers which give you 'compilation error' as a sole output. Reminds me of my early days when I was learning basic, and the best you'd get was 'Error 5 in line 25' - but even than it would give you a line at least.

Comment: @SergeyA, usually Ideone does print compiler errors, see eg https://ideone.com/UQzO2A This time it didn't which makes me even more perplexed

Comment: Doesn't godbolt allow you to do something similar, _and_ choose which compiler to use? That seems like a better go-to for this kind of test

Comment: Anyways, it's better to turn the warnings on: https://wandbox.org/permlink/aJwp2JOZtvrQcil4

Comment: @TimRandall godbolt doesn't run the code, it only compiles it (and shows you the assembly). Wandbox lets you run it and see the output (and supports choosing from dozens of versions of GCC or Clang to compile with). Coliru also let's you run it, and choose from GCC or Clang. They're all useful in slightly different ways.

Comment: Title should read "is ideone an awful site?"

Comment: @JonathanWakely thanks for the info. I never considered the importance of seeing the output in this case. I just assumed that the compiler would produce a warning or error (or not, if configured to be lax). It never would have occurred to me to expect UB from the code.

Comment: Because it's not UB. But the test includes `cout << i << '\n';` and so inspecting the output is presumably relevant in this case. It's just unfortunate that ideone seems to be broken and so confused the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no undefined behavior, the standard allows *name hiding*, it is covered in [[basic.scope.hiding]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.hiding):

> A declaration of a name in a nested declarative region hides a declaration of the same name in an enclosing declarative region; see [basic.scope.declarative] and [basic.lookup.unqual].

and [[basic.scope.declarative]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.declarative) says:

> Every name is introduced in some portion of program text called a declarative region, which is the largest part of the program in which that name is valid, that is, in which that name may be used as an unqualified name to refer to the same entity.
>   In general, each particular name is valid only within some possibly discontiguous portion of program text called its scope.
>   To determine the scope of a declaration, it is sometimes convenient to refer to the potential scope of a declaration.
>   The scope of a declaration is the same as its potential scope unless the potential scope contains another declaration of the same name.
>   In that case, the potential scope of the declaration in the inner (contained) declarative region is excluded from the scope of the declaration in the outer (containing) declarative region.

and gives the following example:

> [ Example: In
>
> ```
> int j = 24;
> int main() {
>   int i = j, j;
>   j = 42;
> }
> ```
>
> the identifier j is declared twice as a name (and used twice). The
>   declarative region of the first j includes the entire example. The
>   potential scope of the first j begins immediately after that j and
>   extends to the end of the program, but its (actual) scope excludes the
>   text between the , and the }. The declarative region of the second
>   declaration of j (the j immediately before the semicolon) includes all
>   the text between { and }, but its potential scope excludes the
>   declaration of i. The scope of the second declaration of j is the same
>   as its potential scope. — end example  ]

Why you see such variable results from IDEone, I don't know. It does not provide a lot of knobs for figuring out what is going on. [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/) is one of several alternatives that provide a lot of knobs and does not exhibit the same variability for this case.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it UB to redeclare a variable within enclosed scope?

No, it is not.

The compiler error you are seeing is most likely caused by the fact that the outer `i` is declared but not used.

Otherwise, your code is just fine.

It works fine for me at https://ideone.com/AwVJqZ as well as my desktop.

Comment: Then why does it behave differently each time it is compiled? And why do the compiler error seem nondeterministic?

Comment: @gaazkam Because IDEOne is garbage?  I'd suggest using [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/) or [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/)

Comment: Declared but not used is not an error, unless someone is compiling with a switch that says to treat warnings as errors. In that case, the compiler does not conform to the language definition and all bets are off.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Conformance does not require that a compiler be able to usefully process any particular program, so long as there exists some (possibly contrived and useless) program which nominally exercises the Translation Limits in N1570 5.2.4.1 which it would process in conformance with the Standard.  Quality implementations shouldn't reject programs without some reason, but the Standard doesn't concern itself with Quality-of-Implementation issues.

Comment: @supercat, yes, and? [intro.compliance] p2 is the relevant reference. I didn't say conformance means accepting and correctly executing every program. The point is that `-Werror=unused-variable` makes GCC non-conforming, because it fails to compile programs which contain no violations of the rules (failing the requirement of [intro.compliance] p2 bullet 2.1). It doesn't reject the program because of its resource limits, it rejects it because `-Werror=unused-variable` explicitly asks for a non-conformance mode. I was responding to a now-deleted comment from Nathan that incorrectly said otherwise